# pass env variables to docker run command from jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins

Yet another question about how to pass env variables.
The task I'm trying to solve: I've got jenkins job which checking out code from git repo, run docker build and docker run commands. I need to pass env variables to this run command. Preferably by using env file, but as single variables will be ok.
Here is my jenkins job:

```
cp WL/${stageid}/env_settings.env ./env_settings.env
ls

docker build \
   -t customer_front${stagePrefix} . 
docker stop customer_front${stagePrefix} || true && docker rm customer_front${stagePrefix} || true
#source env_settings.env
docker run \
      -d --restart unless-stopped \
      -e CLIENT_URL='https://test.customer.app' \
      -e SITE_NAME='My best site' \
      --name customer_front${stagePrefix} \
      -p ${externalPort}:3000 \
      -e DEFAULT_LOCALE=$DEFAULT_LOCALE \
      -e COUNTRY=$COUNTRY \
      -e CURRENCY=$CURRENCY \
      customer_front${stagePrefix}
```

I tried pass variables as run command options, I tried store variables in `env_settings.env` file and then pass it with `--env-file` option. Both variants didn't work.
The only thing that worked was declare args in dockerfile, then declare env vars in dockerfile and pass them in build command, but this variant isn't suitable for me. May be someone had the same problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Is this a pipeline or freestyle job?

Comment: ordinary job, not a jenkins pipeline

Comment: What do you mean "Both variants didn't work"?  What did you see exactly?  What did your file look like?

Comment: I didn't see these variables from app running in the container. Having `ARG API_CLIENT_URL` and `ENV CLIENT_URL=$API_CLIENT_URL` in dockerfile and running `docker build  --build-arg API_CLIENT_URL=https://test.customer.app` did solve the issue. Using this way I was able to access CLIENT_URL from the app

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins there is some really nice docs at the [official Jenkins docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Example:

```
stage("some:job") {
  steps {
     script {
        def args = "-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x"
        docker.image('localstack/localstack:0.12.0').withRun("${args}") { c ->
          sh "echo hi"

        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: See @rudolfninja's comment to his question: "_ordinary job, not a jenkins pipeline_".